# What is the difference between __i686.get_pc_thunk and __x86.get_pc_thunk?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, position-independent-code

These helper functions are used by GCC and Clang in 32-bit x86 position-independent code to get the current execution address into a register, for example:

```
call    __i686.get_pc_thunk.bx
addl    $_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_, %ebx
movl    $2, 4(%esp)
leal    .LC0@GOTOFF(%ebx), %eax
movl    %eax, (%esp)
call    dlopen@PLT
```

It seems the implementations are equivalent:

```
__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx:
    movl    (%esp), %ebx
    ret

__i686.get_pc_thunk.bx:
    movl (%esp), %ebx
    ret
```

Is there any difference besides the name change (seems i686 is older)? And is there a reason for the i686 prefix instead of i386?

Answer (score 2):

So, after some digging in commit history and bug trackers I think I mostly figured it out.

Long time ago, glibc used to have its own handling of PIC code which involved a [call/pop pattern](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/af5fac2f3b031aa0d6e9c1b0e2c2ae737f984c11/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/sysdep.h#L82) to get the GOT address.

[Around 2002](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commit;h=145aacc2e0507dd42a80ae293bbe70f184d08272), `__i686.get_pc_thunk.*`, which did a similar task, was added to GCC, initially as an internal symbol.

Shortly afterwards it [ended up in glibc](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/9df63767d4078fdaf90307f5aa153422f7ec0722/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/sysdep.h#L129) too, probably to avoid code duplication when being compiled with GCC.

However, when built for Pentium 2 or later (`-march=i686`), GCC defined preprocessor macro `__i686=1`, breaking glibc's compilation of the stub code. The problem [has been discovered](https://sourceware.org/legacy-ml/libc-alpha/2002-10/msg00156.html) quite early but for several years glibc used [various workarounds](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/commit/d4a54ac6494dd47a9c3d490e02897c69c0432341) to handle this.

In 2011 (GCC 4.7?) [the name was changed](https://gcc.gnu.org/git?p=gcc.git;a=commit;h=070f36cf077d9cfbfe737712f61a9ff5a3c49820) to `__x86.get_pc_thunk.*` and glibc [added some checks](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/commit/314054eaef2aec965d2f1bced7e86abca118463e) to use a matching name. Eventually support for old GCC versions was dropped together with the old name. Both GCC and glibc only use `__x86.get_pc_thunk.*` now (although GCC can also generate the inline call/pop version).

So, in summary:

There is no actual difference between the two, the name change is simply historical due to a predefined macro collision.

References:

https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git&a=search&h=HEAD&st=commit&s=get_pc_thunk

https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git&a=search&st=commit&s=get_pc_thunk

https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=411

https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=4507

Answer (score 1):

Just a different name choice, not significant AFAIK.

i686 is the standard name for 32-bit code using PPro new instructions like CMOV and FCOMI, and 586 CMPGXCHG and CPUID.  Modern GNU/Linux distros typically configure gcc to use that as the default target for `-m32` 32-bit code, instead of truly baseline i386.  e.g. gcc -v will show `i686-linux-gnu` for a 32-bit build of GCC.

Usually clang uses `call next_insn` / `pop reg` to read EIP into a register.  (Fun fact: that actually *doesn't* break return-address prediction on CPUs other than original Pentium-Pro or Via Nano3000: http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2018/04/ras-microbenchmarks/#call0 - CPUs special case `call  rel32=0` as not being a real call and don't put the return address into the predictor stack.)

---

The `get_pc_thunk.bx` includes the name of the register to return in.  32-bit PIC code used to only ever use EBX as the GOT pointer register, but GCC can now pick any convenient register and emit a thunk function for it, like `....get_pc_thunk.ax` so leaf functions don't have to save/restore EBX.

PIE does make executables slower, by maybe 15% for 32-bit code vs. a couple percent for 64-bit code.  x86-64 has RIP-relative addressing which avoids the need for these thunks.  IMO a 32-bit PIE isn't worth the price, unless you really need more hardening against ROP and Spectre attacks by having ASLR of the main executable.